# Support defunct javascript post deploy

Tags: javascript, deployment, single-page-application

**Background:**

I have a single page JavaScript website that is deployed to production at least once a day. It gets a reasonable amount of traffic and users remain on it for a fair amount of time until they checkout and the JavaScript interacts with the backend through XHR.

**Problem:**

After deploy the JavaScript that is loaded in the browser may no longer be compatible with the backend (Rails in this case).

**Possible Solutions:**

**a)** Compare the asset pipeline fingerprint on a regular interval, window.confirm with a reload request if it is not the same.

**b)** Send a X-JS-fingerprint header with the XHR requests, if it is incompatible return a 409 Conflict which the JavaScript will trigger an error and a window.confirm to reload.

**c)** Run two backends; one that is deployed immediately with new JS and new backend code *(SERVER-1)*, the other remains supporting the old JavaScript XHR request formats *(SERVER-2)*. Like **b)** the X-JS-fingerprint header would be sent but instead of a 409 it would send a 307 Temporary Redirect to SERVER-2 to complete the request. Once the old sessions are all cleared down SERVER-2 is deployed and shutdown until it's needed again.

I'm interested if anyone has thought about this problem before. If you have any thoughts on this subject please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [diffable](https://code.google.com/p/diffable/) project once created in google for similar usecase. 
The basic idea behind it is that is somewhat similar to your variant **a**. With the only difference that when client detects that server updated it updates clientside codebase automatically and does not load all resources but instead loads diff patches and applies them on the client. This may sound a little crazy but it actually makes sense from performance point of view.

There is also a successor idea which uses localStorage to store clientside codebase. Take a look also at https://github.com/plotnikoff/connect-diffable it's a Node project but may still be useful just for getting the idea.

You can alter the approach for you case and have something like:

1. Store clientside assests in localStorage Have checksum for every version
2. Every now or often request the server to detect if new version was rolled out
3. If there is newer version, request for patch    and apply it to assets in localStorage, check the checksum. (Here you    may want to sent checksums of new versions along with the patches to    compare them after applying).

Comment: I like this technique, I will investigate how difficult it will be to implement in the current project. Thanks.

Comment: After investigation, I have found that there is something in this. Implementation is not entirely the same because I am loading the entire javascript rather than the deltas. This works quite well for procedural methods but any initialized objects remain in memory as they were, which in my case is almost every object. There is merit in trying to re-initialize everything that is needed, state is handled in history and document.location.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem as well. My solution is very simple and doesn't really try to avoid errors for the user. It's similar to your solution **a**.

I keep a version number, like a fingerprint (all files are fingerprinted as well, CSS/JS). The deploy process automatically increments the version number. Even if I just changed one line of CSS, the version number is incremented. I don't make a distinction between major or minor version changes, that's only semantics.

The application pings the server every so often to check the version. If the version changes a *"please reload the page"* popup will appear. (A non-intrusive little *thingie* at the top of the page that is very visible and obvious and demands to be clicked).
If the user doesn't reload you can possibly run into errors so I also disable error reporting if the version mismatches.

This solution only ensures that *eventually* people will switch to the new version and you wont get any errors while users are switching. It does nothing to migrate old sessions or prevent errors for the user.

I wouldn't do `window.confirm`. Unexpected modal dialogs are *very* annoying. If you happen to be typing something and you press `[space-bar]` or `[enter]` the dialog disappears and you missed it.

Solution **b** may seem nice but there is a flip side. You'll be able to detect the version mismatch earlier, but it might also mean your users see more errors. If only a small portion of the website was affected by the update any XHR request will fail, even if it didn't need to fail. That is something to consider.

Solution **c** is very nice for the user but might make upgrading hell. What if your database model changes? The old server wont be able to manipulate the data properly, queries will fail etc.

---

I like solution **a** because it's very simple and if you update frequently with many small changes the impact of each update is very small.

Comment: Did you monitor the reloads at all (users who reloaded vs didn't reload)? Did you observe any user frustration (abandonment, etc after displaying the notice)?

Comment: I am not currently monitoring anything regarding this feature. The applications I make don't have the volume to produce any statistical significance.